# Can't hit site with Traefik in Docker

Tags: docker, networking, traefik, docker-network, octoprint

I'm new to Docker and newer to Traefik, but I tried going through the documentation, examples, and questions regarding this - and it still doesn't work.

I have a Raspberry Pi running Linux 4.19.118-v7 on which I've installed Docker. I also have [OctoPrint](https://octoprint.org/) installed as a service which is in a working state. When setup with HAProxy, I have full access to it.

I tried installing Traefik with Docker, disable HAProxy, and let Traefik handle the connection.
Traefik works, as I can see its dashboard, but the way I routed everything gives me a `Bad Gateway` (502) response.

I can do a `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000` on the Pi which returns me the page I want, so there's something there, just not accessible with Traefik.

I have three files responsible:

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2.7
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --providers.docker
    container_name: "traefik"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8088:8080"
      # The HTTPS port
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
      - "./conf/traefik_dynamic.yml:/conf/traefik_dynamic.yml"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
    networks:
      - traefik-network

networks:
  traefik-network:
    external:
      name: traefik_default
```

I run this with `docker -f ./docker-compose.yml up -d`.

It picks up the static configuration file **traefik.yml**:

```
## STATIC CONFIGURATION
log:
  level: DEBUG

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:

  web:
    address: ":80"

  webSecure:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  file:
    directory: /conf
    watch: true

certificatesResolvers:
  lets-encr:
    acme:
      #caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      storage: acme.json
      email: myActual@emailNotShown.io
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web
```

And the dynamic configurations of **conf/trafik_dynamic.yml**:

```
http:

  routers:
    to-octoprint:
      rule: "Host(`3d.myWebsite.io`)"
      service: octoprint
      entryPoints:
        - web

  services:

    octoprint:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

  providers:
    docker: {}
```

This all result in the `Bad Gateway` when I try to hit `http://3d.myWebsite.io` (not my real site, mind you), so I went to the log in Debug mode.
It spits out 4 lines twice per request:

```
msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="..." 

msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: Forwarding this request to URL" Request="..." ForwardURL="http://127.0.0.1:5000"

msg="'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused"

msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: completed ServeHttp on request" Request="..."
```

The request looks like this:

```
{
  "Method": "GET",
  "URL": {
    "Scheme": "",
    "Opaque": "",
    "User": null,
    "Host": "",
    "Path": "/",
    "RawPath": "",
    "ForceQuery": false,
    "RawQuery": "",
    "Fragment": ""
  },
  "Proto": "HTTP/1.1",
  "ProtoMajor": 1,
  "ProtoMinor": 1,
  "Header": {
    "Accept": [
      "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    ],
    "Accept-Encoding": [
      "gzip, deflate"
    ],
    "Accept-Language": [
      "en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8,jv;q=0.7,sv;q=0.6,nb;q=0.5,nl;q=0.4"
    ],
    "Cache-Control": [
      "max-age=0"
    ],
    "Connection": [
      "keep-alive"
    ],
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": [
      "1"
    ],
    "User-Agent": [
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    ],
    "X-Forwarded-Host": [
      "3d.myWebsite.io"
    ],
    "X-Forwarded-Port": [
      "80"
    ],
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
      "http"
    ],
    "X-Forwarded-Server": [
      "db3b41941e8c"
    ],
    "X-Real-Ip": [
      "192.168.1.1"
    ]
  },
  "ContentLength": 0,
  "TransferEncoding": null,
  "Host": "3d.myWebsite.io",
  "Form": null,
  "PostForm": null,
  "MultipartForm": null,
  "Trailer": null,
  "RemoteAddr": "192.168.1.1:56060",
  "RequestURI": "/",
  "TLS": null
}
```

The `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` that allowed this to work now looks as so:

```sh
global
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        log 127.0.0.1 local1 debug

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor
        maxconn 2000
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  15min
        timeout server  15min

#frontend public
#        bind :::80 v4v6
#        bind :::443 v4v6 ssl crt /etc/ssl/snakeoil.pem
#        option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
#        use_backend webcam if { path_beg /webcam/ }
#        default_backend octoprint

#backend octoprint
#        acl needs_scheme req.hdr_cnt(X-Scheme) eq 0

#        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*) \1\ /\2
#        reqadd X-Scheme:\ https if needs_scheme { ssl_fc }
#        reqadd X-Scheme:\ http if needs_scheme !{ ssl_fc }
#        option forwardfor
#        server octoprint1 127.0.0.1:5000
#        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-no-octoprint.http

#backend webcam
#        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /webcam/(.*)     \1\ /\2
#        server webcam1  127.0.0.1:8080
#        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-no-webcam.http
```

What can I do?

Comment: You set a network to traefik, so I guess the octoprint service is not accessible in this network

Comment: @SergioSantiago - So, should I just delete that part, or can I write something else?

Comment: Update - I removed the network part in ``docker-compose.yml``, but I still get ``Bad Gateway``

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to redirect the request to `127.0.0.1` of traefik's docker container, but the service is running in a different container or directly in the host.

You can either:

- link both containers, in the same docker compose file, and access it by name
- or you can run traefik container with `--net=host` in case your service is running in host directly